# How to remove the word "Notes" from \usepackage{endnote}?

Tags: endnotes

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\begin{document}

text\endnote{test footnote}

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

The there will be a word "Note" in front of the notes, how to remove this word "Notes"?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `\renewcommand*{\enoteheading}{}` to remove the heading completely.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\renewcommand*{\enoteheading}{}% removes the heading comletely
\begin{document}

text\endnote{test footnote}

\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

If only text »Notes« (but not the vertical space) should be reomved (or replaced), redefine  `\notesname`.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\renewcommand*{\notesname}{}% removes only the name 
\begin{document}

text\endnote{test footnote}

\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a beginner latex user, thus no expert at all. But yet, I found a solution by adding `\def\notesname{\relax}` in the definitions of the endnotes.

Comment: The other answer has `\renewcommand*{\notesname}{}%` which should do something similar here. But note that that still typesets a heading with empty title. If you want to get rid of the heading properly, the other answer suggests a better solution. In any case I recommend to avoid `\def` and use the LaTeX commend `\renewcommand`.

Comment: `def\notesname{\relax` don't leave the space for the notes title as well.

Comment: Mhh, in my test `\def\notesname{\relax}` *does* leave a space, while `\renewcommand*{\enoteheading}{}` as in esdd's answer doesn't. In any case, if you want to retain the space, I think esdd's alternative suggestion of `\renewcommand*{\notesname}{}` is preferable over `\def\notesname{\relax}` since it uses LaTeX's `\renewcommand` instead of TeX's `\def`.

Comment: I did that using exam doc class. It worked for me.

Comment: Mhhh, I get structurally the same behaviour with `\documentclass{article}` and `\documentclass{exam}`. `\renewcommand*{\notesname}{}%` removes the space induced by the section heading. `\def\notesname{\relax}` and the preferable `\renewcommand*{\notesname}{}` don't. Can you see a difference between your suggestion `\def\notesname{\relax}` and the in my eyes preferable `\renewcommand*{\notesname}{}` in your document?

Comment: Well, tomorrow I will show you the piece of a code on which I successfully applied that command. But I dropped this approach becouse I managed, with the help of tex stack's members collaboration, to implement newbox on the document I'm typesetting. All the time reading books and posts brought a nice results.